# How to change stringified numbers in data frame into pure numeric values in R

Tags: string, r, numbers, dataframe

I have the following data.frame:

```
employee <- c('John Doe','Peter Gynn','Jolie Hope')
# Note that the salary below is in stringified format.
# In reality there are more  such stringified numerical columns.
salary <- as.character(c(21000, 23400, 26800))
df <- data.frame(employee,salary)
```

The output is:

```
> str(df)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ employee: Factor w/ 3 levels "John Doe","Jolie Hope",..: 1 3 2
 $ salary  : Factor w/ 3 levels "21000","23400",..: 1 2 3
```

What I want to do is to convert the change the value from string into pure number
straight fro the `df` variable. At the same time preserve the string name for `employee`. 
I tried this but won't work:

```
as.numeric(df)
```

At the end of the day I'd like to perform arithmetic on these numeric 
values from `df`. Such as `df2 <- log2(df)`, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, there's a couple of things going on here:

- R has two different datatypes that look like strings: `factor` and `character`
- You can't modify most R objects in place, you have to change them by assignment

The actual fix for your example is:

```
df$salary = as.numeric(as.character(df$salary))
```

If you try to call `as.numeric` on `df$salary` without converting it to `character` first, you'd get a somewhat strange result:

```
> as.numeric(df$salary)
[1] 1 2 3
```

When R creates a factor, it turns the unique elements of the vector into levels, and then represents those levels using integers, which is what you see when you try to convert to numeric.